# Protected Intent Confusion

Tags: android

I used this piece of code to turn on and off airplane mode of a Android 4.1.2 device:

```
boolean isEnabled = Settings.System.getInt(
                     getContentResolver(),
                     Settings.System.AIRPLANE_MODE_ON, 0) == 1;
         Settings.System.putInt(
                 getContentResolver(),
                 Settings.System.AIRPLANE_MODE_ON, isEnabled ? 0 : 1);

         Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_AIRPLANE_MODE_CHANGED);
         intent.putExtra("state", !isEnabled);
         sendBroadcast(intent);
```

But after reading the docs I got confused, because this is what it says:

```
public static final String ACTION_AIRPLANE_MODE_CHANGED
Broadcast Action: The user has switched the phone into or out of Airplane Mode. One or more radios have been turned off or on. The intent will have the following extra value:

    state - A boolean value indicating whether Airplane Mode is on. If true, then cell radio and possibly other radios such as bluetooth or WiFi may have also been turned off

**This is a protected intent that can only be sent by the system.**
```

So how come the code works and I am sending this intent when it says it is a **protected intent**?

Comment: Because it was not a protected `Intent` in the beginning, most likely. Android 4.1.2 is three years old; a lot has changed since then.

Comment: @CommonsWare that's what I thought, but when I choose API level 16 (which is 4.1.2) the docs didn't change as I expected, that's why I got confused. Shouldn't the docs change according to the selected API level?

Comment: "Shouldn't the docs change according to the selected API level?" -- no. That just greys out methods, fields, etc. that did not exist at that time. It does not load in new descriptions.

Comment: @CommonsWare what would happen if I try to broadcast this intent in a newer version of Android where it is protected? I can't see any throw exceptions in the docs about sendBroadcast method. Would it crash the app or nothing will happen?

Comment: I have not tried it personally. IIRC, from other Stack Overflow questions, an exception gets logged, though I am not certain if it is an exception that is thrown in your process or one that is thrown elsewhere. "I can't see any throw exceptions" -- many `RuntimeException` subclasses are not documented. For example, you can get a `SecurityException` when calling `startActivity()`, but that is not documented.